# How to implement directory deph in java program that dispaly directory sizes?

Tags: java, recursion, directory

Code:

```
public class DirSize
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DirSize ds = new DirSize();
        System.out.println(ds.getDirSizeInMegabytes(new File("c:/temp")));
    }

    long getDirSize(File dir)
    {
        long size = 0;

        if (dir.isFile())
        {
            size = dir.length();
        }
        else
        {
            File[] subFiles = dir.listFiles();

            for (File file : subFiles)
            {
                if (file.isFile())
                {
                    size += file.length();
                }
                else
                {
                    size += this.getDirSize(file);
                    System.out.println("Directory " + file.getName()
                                       + " size = " + size / 1021 / 1024);
                }
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    long getDirSizeInMegabytes(File dir)
    {
        return this.getDirSize(dir) / 1024 / 1024;
    }
}
```

I would like to print size only directories that on the e.g. 2-nd level from initial:

```
c:\temp1\temp2
```

but if there also temp3:

```
c:\temp1\temp2\temp3 its size shouldn't be printed.
```

Like:

```
 c:\temp1\temp2 size = 10M
 c:\temp1\temp21 size = 15M
 ....
```

How it can be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void getDirSize(File dir,depth) {
    long size = 0;

    if (dir.isFile()) {
        size = dir.length();
    } else {
        depth++;
        File[] subFiles = dir.listFiles();

        for (File file : subFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                size += file.length();
            } else {
                size += this.getDirSize(file,depth);
                if(depth==1) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + file.getName()
                        + " size = " + size / 1021 / 1024);
}
            }

        }
    }

}
```

then call

```
getDirSize(new File("c:/temp"),0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add recursion depth to your recursive method, to be able to limit what is printed:

```
long getDirSize(File dir, int depth, int printDepth)
```

Then you need recursion call like this:

```
size += this.getDirSize(file, depth+1, printDepth);
```

And if you meant you want to print only sizes at maxdepth, then you need to add test like

```
if (depth == printDepth) { // or depth <= printDepth maybe
    // ...do printing only for these
}
```

---

It might make sense to wrap the whole thing in a class, so you could make printDepth a member variable, and the recursive method private, something like:

```
class DirSizePrinter {
    int printDepth;
    File root;
    public DirSizePrinter(int printDepth, File root) {
        this.printDepth = printDepth;
        this.root = root;
    }

    public long printSize() {
        return printSizeRecursive(0);
    }

    private long printSizeRecursive(int depth) {
        // ... code from question with depth added, and using printDepth and root
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    new DirSizePrinter(3, "C:/temp").printSize();
```

Or some variation of this, depending on all the requirements you have.